# Logging out of the Site doesent work properly. / If site doesent load close Browser and reopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

So I have written a Script in Python that Logs into an Account Collects some Currency and logs out and it loops through a lot of Accounts. It's easily a script for Collecting this Currency with tons of Accounts. The Problem is every time the Script needs to Logout it clicks on the Logout button but if it goes to the Sign-up page again it says that it is still logged in . BTW Sometimes the site doesent load and the script just closes itself does somebody know on how to implement a function that reloads the page or reopens the chromedriver?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import traceback
from time import sleep 

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\klime\Desktop\Python Palai Bot\chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
lines = open('acc.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

for l in lines:
    try:

        print("Trieng to connect to Palai.org")
        browser.get('https://www.palai.org/u/sign_in')
        print("Successfully connected to Palai.org!")

        print("Trieng to Log into the Account: ", l)
        email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_id("user_email")))
        email.send_keys(l)

        password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"user_password")))
        password.send_keys("mypassword")

        commit = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_name('commit')))
        commit.click()
        print("Successfully logged in!")

        collect = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_link_text('Abholen')))
        collect.click()

        collectTwo = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"app\"]/article/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/form/input[1]')))
        collectTwo.click()
        print("Successfully collected Palai")

        print("Transfering...")
        browser.get('https://palai.org/a/kliment+843fb7f2d-f17f-4f86-8365-0aeaf61f566e/pay?transfer_amount=176PALAI')

        email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_id("user_email")))
        email.send_keys(l)

        password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"user_password")))
        password.send_keys("mypassword")

        commit = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_name('commit')))
        commit.click()
        print("Successfully logged in now Transfering Palai...")

        submit = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_id('submit_transfer')))
        submit.click()
        print("Successfully transferd the Palai to the Main Account!")

        print("Logging out...")
        logout = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("form.button_to > button")))
        logout.click()
        sleep(10)
        print("Successfully logged out of the Account!")

    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        browser.quit()

browser.quit()
```

This is the error I am getting after

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========== RESTART: C:\Users\klime\Desktop\Python Palai Bot\Bot.py ==========
Trieng to connect to Palai.org
Successfully connected to Palai.org!
Trieng to Log into the Account:  thisismyemail@myemail.com
Successfully logged in!
Successfully collected Palai
Transfering...
Successfully logged in now Transfering Palai...
Successfully transferd the Palai to the Main Account!
Logging out...
Successfully logged out of the Account!
Trieng to connect to Palai.org
Successfully connected to Palai.org!
Trieng to Log into the Account:  thisismyemail2@myemail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\klime\Desktop\Python Palai Bot\Bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element_by_id("user_email")))
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"user_email"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

Trieng to connect to Palai.org
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\klime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0476D390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte
```

Well the script should logout normally without any Problems, and if the Browser doesent load a page the Browser just gets closed and reopened.

Comment: Well, for one thing in your exception handling you are explicitly telling the browser to quit and never restarting it, so this is bound to happen any time you encounter any exception.  Another comment I'd make is that while your print statements can tell you whether that code is reached without exception, they do not actually indicate that the previous action taken was successful; to do this you'll need to assert on an element on the new page or something of that sort.  Finally, for your problem, could you simply close the browser at the end of the loop and reopen it at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code block was near perfect. As you are trying to send a *character sequence* to the desired fields, instead of using the `expected_conditions` of `visibility_of()`, you need to use **`element_to_be_clickable()`** as follows:

```
print("Trieng to connect to Palai.org")
browser.get('https://www.palai.org/u/sign_in')
# WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Log in – Palai (beta)"))
print("Successfully connected to Palai.org!")

print("Trieng to Log into the Account: ", l)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "user_email"))).send_keys(l)
browser.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys("mypassword")
browser.find_element_by_name('commit').click()
print("Successfully logged in!")
```

Comment: For some reason i couldn't copy the error so i just made a Screenshot http://prntscr.com/ni19p9

Comment: @Kliment I have commented the line, can you try once now?

Comment: Now it works but now there is the other problem. It logsout and opens the sign in page again to login into the next account but for some reason it says that i am already logged in. http://prntscr.com/ni1rba

Comment: @Kliment Seems the algorithm you are using needs to be modified but that would be a different question altogether. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: What do you mean @DebanjaB